# Changing DataVisualization.Chart size without using WinForms

Tags: c#, web-services, charts, resize, data-visualization

I have an Web Service that generates different kinds of charts.
The charts are generated programatically using `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` and they are saved to .png files. But whatever I do, the charts have the dimension 300x300 pixels.

On the internet I have found many solutions on changing the size of the chart, but they only apply to situations where the chart is put into a WinForm and then saved to a file.

How can I change the size of the chart if I don't have WinForms in my application?

This is a dummy example of what I do in my code

```
int[] yVal = { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
string[] xName = { "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b" };

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart Chart1 = new Chart();
Chart1.Titles.Add("Title");
Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());

Chart1.Series[0].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
Chart1.Series[0].YValueType = ChartValueType.Int32;
Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(xName, yVal);

Chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.EarthTones;

Chart1.Legends.Add(new Legend());
Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = false;

ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
chartArea.AxisX.Title = "X";
chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Y";
Chart1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);


Chart1.SaveImage("chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: @Zak I added an dummy example of what I do in my code, if it can be of any help. Nothing else but I simple chart creation.

Comment: @CoralDoe The answer below is a little late coming, but perhaps it will be of value anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a 1000px x 1000px large image, add the following line after the chart initialization:

```
Chart1.Size = new Size(1000, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't actually believe that the answer was so simple. It isn't late; I just left the application with those small charts, but now it has been improved.